# Java Game Leveling Up

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out a way to navigate from one level to another 3 times. I have 3 game levels and I'm trying to level up to go from level 1 to level 2, and from level 2 to level 3. Right now it goes from level 1 to level 3 and then from level 3 to level 3 again. I know I'm going wrong somewhere, can anyone help:

My 3 levels extends my `GameLevel` class, and my main class is `Game`, where `goToNextLevel` method is created (which stops the current level and levels up while populating it).

```
package game;
public class Game {

    /** The World in which the bodies move and interact. */
    private GameLevel world;

    /** A graphical display of the world (a specialized JPanel). */
    private UserView view;

    private int level;

    private Controller controller;

    private SoundClip gameMusic;

    /** Initialize a new Game. */
    public Game() {
        // make the world
        level = 1;
        world = new Level1();
        world.populate(this);
        try {
            gameMusic = new SoundClip("data/backgroundaudio.wav");   // Open an audio input stream
            gameMusic.loop();  // Set it to continous playback (looping)
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException|IOException|LineUnavailableException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } 
        // make a view
        view = new MyView(world, world.getPlayer(), 1250, 700);
        // uncomment this to draw a 1-metre grid over the view
        // view.setGridResolution(1);
        // display the view in a frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Collect All The Snowballs And Pick Up The Keys!");
        // quit the application when the game window is closed
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        // display the world in the window
        frame.add(view);
        // don't let the game window be resized
        ColourPanel colourPanel = new ColourPanel(view);
        frame.add(colourPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        // size the game window to fit the world view
        frame.pack();
        // make the window visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // get keyboard focus
        frame.requestFocus();
        // give keyboard focus to the frame whenever the mouse enters the view
        view.addMouseListener(new GiveFocus(frame));
        controller = new Controller(world.getPlayer());
        frame.addKeyListener(controller);
        // start!
        world.start();
    }

    /** The player in the current level. */
    public SnowCollector getPlayer() {
        return world.getPlayer();
    }

    /** Is the current level of the game finished? */
    public boolean isCurrentLevelCompleted() {
        return world.isCompleted();

    }

    /** Advance to the next level of the game. */
    public void goNextLevel() {
        world.stop();
        if (level == 3) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else  {
            level++;
            // get a new world
            world = new Level2();
            // fill it with bodies
            world.populate(this);
            // switch the keyboard control to the new player
            controller.setBody(world.getPlayer());
            // show the new world in the view
            view.setWorld(world);
            world.start();
        }
    }

    /** Run the game. */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

Below is my `GameLevel` class that the class of each of my 3 levels extends

```
/**
 * A level of the game.
 */
public abstract class GameLevel extends World {
    private SnowCollector player;

    public SnowCollector getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    /**
     * Populate the world of this level.
     * Child classes should this method with additional bodies.
     */
    public void populate(Game game) {
        player = new SnowCollector(this);
        player.setPosition(startPosition());
        Door door = new Door(this);
        door.setPosition(doorPosition());
        door.addCollisionListener(new DoorListener(game));
    }

    /** The initial position of the player. */
    public abstract Vec2 startPosition();

    /** The position of the exit door. */
    public abstract Vec2 doorPosition();

    /** Is this level complete? */
    public abstract boolean isCompleted();
}
```

This code is where the `goToNextLevel` method is called when my main character makes contact with a door

```
package game;

/**
 * Listener for collision with a door.  When the player collides with a door,
 * if the current level is complete the game is advanced to the next level. 
 */
public class DoorListener implements CollisionListener {
    private Game game;

    public DoorListener(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void collide(CollisionEvent e) {
        SnowCollector player = game.getPlayer();
        if (e.getOtherBody() == player && game.isCurrentLevelCompleted()) {
            System.out.println("Going to next level...");
            **game.goNextLevel();**
        }
    }
}
```

I know the problem is with the `game.goToNextLevel()` method at the top.

Comment: @JohannesJander I think OP has made some mistakes with SO's TextArea's options, since the `enter code here` are added when you click the `{}`-button. I (and _TaZz_ as well by the looks of it) have edited the post to correct the format of the entire question.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ah, OK, that's possible. Retracting comment.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen can you help me answer the question

Comment: Try to debug it. set a watch on your level attribute and see how it works

Answer (score 0):

```
world = new Level2();
```

Creates a world of the type Level2. I don't think that's what you want because it would mean each level up goes into the same level again (but only twice)

Though it still wouldn't react the way you described... unless you start in Level0 or something, then it would be exactly how you described.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
public static int l1 = 50;
public static int l2 = 105;
public static int l3 = 170;
public static int l4 = 210;
public static int pl = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    level_System();
}
public static void level_System() {
    pl = 55;
    if (pl >= l1) {
        pl -= l1;
        System.out.print("you leveled up\nLEVEL: 2\nxp left ");
        System.out.println(l2 - pl);
        System.out.print("current xp " + pl);
    } else if (pl >= l2) {
        System.out.println("you leveled up\nLEVEL: 3\nxp left ");
    } else if (pl >= l3) {
        System.out.println("you leveled up\nLEVEL: 4\nxp left ");
    } else if (pl >= l4) {
        System.out.println("you leveled up\nLEVEL: 5\nxp  left ");
    }

}
}
```

You dont have to include public with your static int i just do it because you never know

Comment: You should describe what changes you've made, and why.